# Javascript "selectElement.add(option, index)" working in Firefox but Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, select, addition

Here's the relevant HTML:

```
<html>
<body>
...
    <select id="class" name="class">
        <option value=0>Select a Class</option>
        <option>IGME-101-##</option>
        <option>IGME-102-##</option>
        <option>IGME-105-##</option>
        <option>IGME-106-##</option>
        <option>IGME-119-##</option>
        <option>IGME-202-##</option>
        <option>IGME-209-##</option>
        <option>IGME-219-##</option>
        <option>IGME-220-##</option>
        <option>IGME-230-##</option>
        <option>IGME-309-##</option>
        <option>IGME-320-##</option>
        <option>IGME-330-##</option>
        <option>IGME-450-##</option>
        <option>IGME-470-##</option>
        <option>IGME-499-##</option>
        <option>IGME-529-##</option>
        <option>IGME-540-##</option>
        <option>IGME-550-##</option>
        <option>IGME-560-##</option>
        <option>IGME-571-##</option>
        <option>IGME-580-##</option>
        <option>IGME-581-##</option>
        <option>IGME-582-##</option>
        <option>IGME-588-##</option>
        <option>IGME-590-##</option>
        <option>IGME-599-##</option>
        <option>IGME-609-##</option>
        <option>IGME-671-##</option>
        <option>IGME-680-##</option>
        <option>IGME-740-##</option>
        <option>IGME-760-##</option>
        <option>IGME-789-##</option>
        <option>IGME-795-##</option>
        <option>IGME-796-##</option>
        <option>IGME-797-##</option>
        <option>IGME-799-##</option>
        <option>IGME-900-##</option>
        <option>IGME-901-##</option>   
    </select>
...
    <input id="ukClass" name="ukClass" type="checkbox" onclick="setClassUnknown()"/>
</body>
</html>
```

And the relevant Javascript:

```
function setClassUnknown() {
        var select = document.getElementById("class");
        if(document.getElementById("ukClass").checked) {
            var opt = document.createElement("option");
            opt.text = "0000-000-00";
            opt.value = "0000-000-00";
            select.add(opt,1);
            select.selectedIndex = 1;
            select.disabled = true;
        }
        else {
            if(select.options[1].value == "0000-000-00") {
                select.remove(1);
            }
            select.selectedIndex = 0;
            if(select.disabled) {
                select.disabled = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

I've been debugging this for a while. It works just fine in Firefox.

What I'm trying to do is dynamically add an option tag to this select menu (at a specific place in the list: 1) when a checkbox is checked, and remove that option when the checkbox is unchecked. Using `console.log` I can see that Chrome creates the new option tag as desired, but it fails to add it to the select menu.

Any idea why this would work in Firefox but not Chrome?

Comment: `<option value="0">Select a Class</option>` value should be quoted

Comment: It works perfectly fine for me in chrome -> http://jsfiddle.net/9aJNd/

Comment: @adeneo I updated your JSFiddle; doesn't work for me in Chrome. http://jsfiddle.net/9aJNd/3/

Comment: So fix it -> http://jsfiddle.net/9aJNd/4/

Answer (score 1):

It seems firefox admits two options:

The regular

```
void add(
  in nsIDOMHTMLElement element,
  in nsIDOMHTMLElement before //Optional from Gecko 7.0
);
```

This one is for HTML5

```
void add(
  in HTMLElement element,
  in long before //Optional from Gecko 7.0
);
```

But Chrome only implements the first one, as one of the comments has pointed. If you pass a number as the second parameter, Chrome ignores it and appends the new element at the end of the list, so your code cannot find it at the first position.

You can fix it making FF adding to the last position (but then you'll have to check how many options you have to select it) or changing the second parameter , passing the current first one.